# Intersection of two numpy arrays of different dimensions by column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, axis, intersection

I have two different numpy arrays given. First one is two-dimensional array which looks like (first ten points):

```
[[  0.           0.        ]
 [ 12.54901961  18.03921569]
 [ 13.7254902   17.64705882]
 [ 14.11764706  17.25490196]
 [ 14.90196078  17.25490196]
 [ 14.50980392  17.64705882]
 [ 14.11764706  17.64705882]
 [ 14.50980392  17.25490196]
 [ 17.64705882  18.03921569]
 [ 21.17647059  34.11764706]]
```

the second array is just one-dimensional which looks like (first ten points):

```
[ 18.03921569  17.64705882  17.25490196  17.25490196  17.64705882
  17.64705882  17.25490196  17.64705882  21.17647059  22.35294118]
```

Values from the second (one-dimension) array could occur in first (two-dimension) one in the first column. F.e. **17.64705882**

I want to get an array from the two-dimension one where values of the first column match values in the second (one-dimension) array. How to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `np.in1d(array1, array2)` to search in `array1` each value of `array2`. In your case you just have to take the first column of the first array:

```
mask = np.in1d(a[:, 0], b)
#array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

You can use this mask to obtain the encountered values:

```
a[:, 0][mask]
#array([ 17.64705882,  21.17647059])
```

Comment: The usual precautions with floating point equality testing apply, e.g. `.1 + .1 + .1 == .3` evaluates to `False`, so unless the values are truly equal, not simply equivalent in non-floating point arithmetic, things can go very wrong.

Comment: @Jaime great comment. Do you know if they have plans to add a `tolerance` parameter to `np.in1d`?

Comment: It could make sense, and for `in1d` it seems to be a well defined problem.  I don't know that anyone working on it, but pull requests are always welcome! ;-)